# Best way to modify values in a list of rules?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, pattern-matching

Recently I had to solve a problem similar to this:

Let's say I have a list of list of rules

```
Clear[a, b, c, d]
l = {{a -> 2, b -> 1, c -> 3, d -> 2}, {d -> 2, b -> 1, a -> 1, c -> 2}, 
     {c -> 3, a -> 1, b -> 2}};
```

What is the best way to sort the values of `{a, b, c}` in each sublist without touching the rest of the sublist. So the first sublist should be:

```
{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 2}
```

and the whole result should be

```
{{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 2}, {d -> 2, b -> 1, a -> 1, c -> 2}, 
 {c -> 3, a -> 1, b -> 2}}
```

There are no duplicates in the subsists (so `a  -> _` appears only once). The order of rules in the sublist does not matter.

In an effort to expand my pattern matching skills I would like to know: What's the best way to achieve this? Here "best" means elegant code, but still efficient enough to work ~10^5 subsists.

```
testdata = 
  Table[MapThread[
    Rule, {RandomSample[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k}, 10], 
     RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10]}], {ii, 10^5}];
```

---

I'm posting my answer below, so that I won't get accused of not showing any effort:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot think of a better approach than your own method therefore I shall recast it in a generalized fashion.

```
With[{T = Thread},
 normRls[l_, pat_] := l /. T[T[pat -> _] -> T[pat -> Sort[pat /. l]]]
]

normRls[#, {a, b, c}] & /@ testdata // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 1.31
> ```

This is however a bit slower than your hard-coded method:

```
normalize /@ testdata // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 1.045
> ```

Okay, let's try a little meta-programming:

```
genRule[x_, {y_}] := (x -> _) :> (x -> Slot[y])

genNorm[pat_List] :=
  With[{body = MapIndexed[genRule, pat]},
    # /. (body &) @@ Sort[pat /. #] &
  ]

genNorm[{a, b, c}] /@ testdata // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.889
> ```

Ah, that's more like it!

---

#### Explanation

A request for explanation of the code was made.  The first method is fairly straightforward after understanding the behavior of `Thread`:

```
Thread[{a, b, c} -> {1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}
> ```

```
Thread[{a, b, c} -> nonlist]
```

> ```
> {a -> nonlist, b -> nonlist, c -> nonlist}
> ```

This is used three separate times, to generate e.g.: `{a -> _, b -> _, c -> _}`
then `{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}`, and then to combine them into:
`{(a -> _) -> a -> 1, (b -> _) -> b -> 2, (c -> _) -> c -> 3}`.

The "meta-programming" method is a bit more involved.

First let's look at the result, then how we get there:

```
genNorm[{q, r, s}]
```

> ```
> #1 /. ({(q -> _) :> q -> #1,
>         (r -> _) :> r -> #2,
>         (s -> _) :> s -> #3} &) @@ Sort[{q, r, s} /. #1] &
> ```

We see that the output is a `Function` (`&`).  This function takes a single argument, the (sub)list of rules to be modified.  Upon it a replacement will eventually be done (`#1 /. ...`).  The rules for that replacement are constructed by an internal `Function`:

```
({(q -> _) :> q -> #1,
  (r -> _) :> r -> #2,
  (s -> _) :> s -> #3} &)
```

the parameters (`#1`, `#2`, `#3`) of which are filled by applying (`@@`) to `Sort[{q, r, s} /. #1]` wherein `#1` is the original (sub)list of rules.  `Sort[{q, r, s} /. #1]` itself is hopefully self-explanatory.  This internal function pulls the needed parts from the sorted list.  For example, with the input:

```
{q -> 21, r -> 11, s -> 31, t -> 21}
```

The output is:

```
{(q -> _) :> q -> 11,
 (r -> _) :> r -> 21,
 (s -> _) :> s -> 31}
```

Which when applied yields:

> ```
> {q -> 11, r -> 21, s -> 31, t -> 21}
> ```

Okay, so how is that function constructed?

The auxiliary function `genRule` is `MapIndexed` over the pattern list:

```
MapIndexed[genRule, {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {(a -> _) :> a -> #1,
>  (b -> _) :> b -> #2,
>  (c -> _) :> c -> #3}
> ```

This expression is then named `body` (using `With`) and injected into: `# /. (body &) @ Sort[pat /. #] &` which you should recognize as the (nested) function detailed above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (+1). Some wonderful ideas. But, I think this answer would be much better if you could ad a line or two explaining what the code does (for those who don't have MMA at hand or are not so proficient -- actually I'm still deciphering the meta-programming trick:).

Comment: @Ajasja Done.  Please tell me if my explanation is satisfactory.  I never know what to include and what to leave out I'm afraid.

Comment: @Ajasja I realize that this can be made faster by using `genNorm[pat_List] := 
 With[{body = MapIndexed[genRule, pat]}, Replace[#, body & @@ Sort[pat /. #], {1}] &]` -- that is replace at level one.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution: I first retrieve the values, sort them and then use rule replacement to apply the changes.

```
Clear@normalize
normalize[l_] := Block[{av, bv, cv},
  (*Get sorted values*)
  {av, bv, cv} = Sort[{a, b, c} /. l];
  (*Modify the original lis*)
  l /. {Rule[a, _] -> Rule[a, av],
    Rule[b, _] -> Rule[b, bv],
    Rule[c, _] -> Rule[c, cv]}
  ]

normalize /@ l
(* out =>
{{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 2}, {d -> 2, b -> 1, a -> 1, 
  c -> 2}, {c -> 3, a -> 1, b -> 2}}
*)
```

---

This takes about 2 seconds on my computer

```
AbsoluteTiming[result = normalize /@ testdata;]
(*=> {2.319133, Null}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative:

```
Clear@sortKeys
sortKeys[list_, keys_] := Module[{keysInList, values, rules},
    {keysInList, values} = (rules = FilterRules[#, keys]) /. Rule -> List // Transpose;       
    # /. MapThread[RuleDelayed, {Sort@rules, Thread[Sort@keysInList -> Sort@values]}]
] & /@ list
```

This first filters the `rules` in a sublist corresponding to the input `keys` (`{a, b, c}`) we wish to sort by and then keeps a separate list of keys that actually appear in the sublist (`keysInList`) and their `values` (this is to handle missing keys). Then it sorts the values and replaces `a -> original value` with `a -> sorted value` (the `MapThread` is used to construct a rule list).

Usage:

```
sortKeys[l, {a, b, c}]
(* {{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 2}, {d -> 2, b -> 1, a -> 1, c -> 2}, 
    {c -> 3, a -> 1, b -> 2}} *)
```

This can be simplified if it can be guaranteed that all the sublists will have all the keys.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think a short sentence explaining what the code does would make this a much better answer.

Comment: @Ajasja Explanation added :)

Comment: Thanks +1. Why is `RuleDelayed` needed? (Instead of a normal `Rule`)

Comment: Probably not needed in this case, but I do it out of habit, when the RHS is a named pattern (or more generally, when it's not something of the form `HeadA -> HeadB` or `SymbolA -> SymbolB`)

Answer (score 2):

In a [comment elsewhere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73098/can-i-sum-or-mulitply-2-columns-in-a-list-of-associations/73104#comment202969_73104), @Mr.Wizard suggested that associations might be useful for this question.  Here is my attempt:

```
normalizeAssoc[keys_][l_] :=
  <| l, AssociationThread[keys -> Sort @ Lookup[l, keys, 0]] |>
```

... and here it is in action:

```
Take[testdata, 2]

(* {{h->0.074356,i->0.756409,f->0.456624,b->-0.0342208,c->0.634687,
     d->0.0939196,e->-0.527057,g->-0.62371,k->-0.41238,a->0.0599702},
    {a->-0.665407,g->0.414135,i->-0.909054,e->-0.727194,c->-0.872878,
     b->-0.125237,j->0.829395,k->-0.416614,h->-0.819966,f->0.815137}} *)

normalizeAssoc[{a, b, c}] /@ Take[testdata, 2]

(* {<|h->0.074356,i->0.756409,f->0.456624,b->0.0599702,c->0.634687,
      d->0.0939196,e->-0.527057,g->-0.62371,k->-0.41238,a->-0.0342208|>,
    <|a->-0.872878,g->0.414135,i->-0.909054,e->-0.727194,c->-0.125237,
      b->-0.665407,j->0.829395,k->-0.416614,h->-0.819966,f->0.815137|>} *)
```

This function operates equally well when the original rules are in list form or in associations.

The question's construction of `testdata` will generate some sublists in which `a`, `b`, or `c` is missing.  The problem statement is silent on how to handle such cases, so I have arbitrarily decided to treat the values of missing keys as zero.  If a different value is appropriate, simply adjust the expression `Lookup[..., 0]`.  It is left as an exercise for the reader if some other strategy is required.

Note that the result contains associations instead of sublists.  If this is unacceptable, then we can use:

```
normalizeAssoc2[keys_][l_] :=
  normalizeAssoc[keys][l] // Normal
```

Naturally, this takes a little longer to run.  Speaking of run time, here are some timings on my machine:

```
    normalizeAssoc               : 1.39s
    normalizeAssoc2              : 2.07s

    normalize (from Ajasja)      : 5.92s
    normRls   (#1 from Mr.Wizard): 4.26s
    genNorm   (#2 from Mr.Wizard): 3.56s
```

Like all microbenchmarks, these timings should be taken with a grain of salt.  I found that the running times of all functions changed radically as new random variations of `testdata` were generated, presumably due to the randomized key order.  However, repeated runs showed that the relative performance of the functions remained reasonably consistent.

Comment: Thank you.  That *is* cleaner than what I had.

Answer (score 0):

edit: this is actually not doing what you want, i sorted the order of the rules
without changing the rules.

```
rulelist = {a -> 1, b -> 2, cc -> 4, c -> -1};
sortpos = Position[ rulelist ,  r_Rule /; MemberQ[{a, b, c}, r[[1]]]];
sorted = Sort[ 
   Take[rulelist, #][[1]] & /@ (sortpos) , #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &];
(rulelist[[sortpos[[#]]]] = sorted[[#]]) & /@ Range[Length[sortpos]];
rulelist

{c -> -1, a -> 1, cc -> 4, b -> 2}
```

Take 2, I think this is what you want, changine the rules so that a-> min value, etc
*and* reordering the rules..  I think it does basically what you did, except I didnt "hard code" the a,b,c into the algotithm.  If performace suffers a tad that might be a fair trade.

```
rulelist = {a -> 1, b -> 2, cc -> 4, c -> -1};
desiredorder = {a, b, c};
values = Sort[ desiredorder /. rulelist];
rulelist = rulelist /. (x_ -> y_) /; 
     MemberQ[desiredorder, x] :> (x ->values[[First[Position[desiredorder, x]][[1]]]]);
sortpos = 
  Position[ rulelist ,  r_Rule /; MemberQ[desiredorder, r[[1]]]];
(rulelist[[sortpos[[#]]]] = desiredorder[[#]] -> values[[#]]) & /@ 
      Range[Length[desiredorder]];


rulelist -> {a -> -1, b -> 1, cc -> 4, c -> 2}
```

(If you dont care about the order of the rules, drop the last two lines)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think a short sentence explaining what the code does would make this a much better answer.