# Can I sum or mulitply 2 columns in a list of associations

Tags: associations

I have a list of associations.  I will need to add 2 columns (or perform some other arithmetic operation) and put the answer in a new column.  For example:

```
{<|Year->2014, ID->1, amt1->10, amt2->20|>
 <|Year->2015, ID->1, amt1->20, amt2->25|> 
 <|Year->2014, ID->2, amt1->11, amt2->21|>}
```

I want to get:

```
{<|Year->2014, ID->1, amt1->10, amt2->20, tot->30|>
 <|Year->2015, ID->1, amt1->20, amt2->25, tot->45|> 
 <|Year->2014, ID->2, amt1->11, amt2->21, tot->32|>}
```

Sometimes I will want to delete the amt1 and amt2, depending on what I'm doing at the time.

I've done this by converting this back into a list of values, operating on the list and putting it back into an association.  But it seems like there must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: similar [How can I add a column into a existing Dataset?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51472/142).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the data from the question:

```
data = {<|Year->2014, ID->1, amt1->10, amt2->20|>,
        <|Year->2015, ID->1, amt1->20, amt2->25|>,
        <|Year->2014, ID->2, amt1->11, amt2->21|>};
```

We can introduce the key `tot` which is the sum of `amt1` and `amt2` like this:

```
<| #, tot -> #[amt1] + #[amt2] |> & /@ data

(*
   {<| Year->2014, ID->1, amt1->10, amt2->20, tot->30 |>,
    <| Year->2015, ID->1, amt1->20, amt2->25, tot->45 |>,
    <| Year->2014, ID->2, amt1->11, amt2->21, tot->32 |>}
*)
```

Should we wish to drop the input keys `amt1` and `amt2`:

```
<| KeyDrop[#, {amt1, amt2}], tot -> #[amt1] + #[amt2] |> & /@ data

(*
   {<| Year->2014, ID->1, tot->200 |>,
    <| Year->2015, ID->1, tot->500 |>,
    <| Year->2014, ID->2, tot->231 |>}
*)
```

In some situations, it might just be easiest to build the result associations from scratch:

```
<| Year -> #[Year], ID -> #[ID], tot -> #[amt1] + #[amt2] |> & /@ data

(*
   {<| Year->2014, ID->1, tot->30 |>,
    <| Year->2015, ID->1, tot->45 |>,
    <| Year->2014, ID->2, tot->32 |>}
*)
```

Comment: WReach, I imagine there is a nice solution to [(19565)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19565/121) using associations but I cannot find a clean formulation.  Would you please consider answering that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I gave it a [shot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/74040/142).

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {<|Year -> 2014, ID -> 1, amt1 -> 10, amt2 -> 20|>,
        <|Year -> 2015, ID -> 1, amt1 -> 20, amt2 -> 25|> , 
        <|Year -> 2014, ID -> 2, amt1 -> 11, amt2 -> 21|>};
```

Don't trust me, it's my 3rd answer about associations, but it works, so here you go:

```
data[[All, Key[tot]]] = Total /@ data[[All, {Key[amt1], Key[amt2]}]];
data
```

> ```
> {<|Year -> 2014, ID -> 1, amt1 -> 10, amt2 -> 20, tot -> 30|>,
>  <|Year -> 2015, ID -> 1, amt1 -> 20, amt2 -> 25, tot -> 45|>, 
>  <|Year -> 2014, ID -> 2, amt1 -> 11, amt2 -> 21, tot -> 32|>}
> ```

Instead of `Part` you can use `Lookup`:

```
Total /@ Lookup[data, {amt1, amt2}, 0]
```

which is shorter and can give default value `0`.

---

more general:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];
f[data_, newKey_, keys_, function_] := data[[All, newKey]] = (function @@@ Lookup[data, keys]);

f[data, "total", Key /@ {Year, ID}, List];
data

{<|Year -> 2014, ID -> 1, amt1 -> 10, amt2 -> 20, "total" -> {2014, 1}|>,
 <|Year -> 2015, ID -> 1, amt1 -> 20, amt2 -> 25, "total" -> {2015, 1}|>,
 <|Year -> 2014, ID -> 2, amt1 -> 11, amt2 -> 21, "total" -> {2014, 2}|>}
```

Comment: That works, thank you.  Suppose I want to multiply the 2 elements, or divide one by the other?  Can I somehow set up a formula to do that?  Or to operate on more than 2 elements.  For example, for 3 elements, to add the first 2 and subtract the third one.

Comment: I guess either.  I just did an example by using the list of associations as just a list.  i.e., data[[All,3]]*data[[All,4]].  This gives me back a list which I'd have to turn back into an association.  Ideally my code would probably be clearer if I used the keys rather than indices.  Also, if it seems that I should just work with lists, and not try to do this inside the association, I can do that.

Comment: Sorry, I see that my previous edit was not at all clear.  What about a case where I want to divide amt1 by amt2?  If I can do that, I should be able to handle most of the situations I'm encountering.

Comment: @MitchellKaplan Then you could do `f[data, Key[div], Key /@ {amt1, amt2}, #/#2 &];`